# FreeRTOS Event posted but not handled

Tags: c, event-handling, embedded, freertos

I have a task which waits for event bits to be set before processing each event. Once an event has been completed I manually clear the individual event flag. However on rare occurrences an event is posted but not processed. How do I ensure that an event is never missed?

```
while(1)
{
  event = xEventGroupWaitBits(measurement_task_event,
        MEASUREMENTTASK_EVENT_ALL, false, false, portMAX_DELAY);

  if (event & EVENT_BIT1)
    {
      //handle event
      xEventGroupClearBits(measurement_task_event, EVENT_BIT1);

    }
}
```

Event 1 is called from the interrupt of a 50ms timer and is by far the most frequent event. Other events are called from a mixture of other tasks and interrupts.

My current theory is that an Event is being posted by an interrupt while the task is in the middle of processing other events. Originally I had

```
  event = xEventGroupWaitBits(measurement_task_event,
        MEASUREMENTTASK_EVENT_ALL, true, false, portMAX_DELAY);
```

Which automatically cleared all flags on completion. I had hoped the change to manually clearing would fix this issue.

What is the correct way to make sure all events are processed?

Comment: Which event(s) is missed, EVENT_BIT1 or another?  Show the code that handles the other events.  The code you've shared is straightforward and I don't see an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have built in a race condition as you are waiting for a bit and clearing the bit separately.  Have a look at the [ClearOnExit parameter](https://www.freertos.org/xEventGroupWaitBits.html).